# Which SSL/TLS protocol will use by cURL if not defined?

Tags: tls, curl

When curl to an HTTPS URL and not not defined the SSL version option, which level of SSL/TLS will be used?

From the cURL documentation it says `CURL_SSLVERSION_DEFAULT` will use as default.

> CURL_SSLVERSION_DEFAULT
>
> The default action. This will attempt to figure out the remote SSL protocol version.

So does it depend on the other end of the connection?

Comment: It varies on which version of curl you're running, on which operating system (and therefore which openssl library is installed).

Answer (score 4):

The SSL protocol involves a handshake where the version is negotiated. The web server and the client will agree on the newest version that they both support. As cURL [supports TLS 1.2](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSLVERSION.html), the newest standardized version, the version of TLS chosen will correspond to the highest version that the server supports unless you restrict cURL's SSL options.

Googling [SSL handshake](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=ssl%20handshake&es_th=1) will give you many references on the version negotiation.